# Creating PDF using CFDocument with header / footer taking very long time to generate

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, header, cfdocument

I am trying to create PDF using below code. It takes more then 2 hours to generate PDF.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=MyReport.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf">
<cfdocument format="PDF" orientation="portrait" marginbottom="1" marginleft="0.5" marginright="0.5" margintop="1" overwrite="true" >
    <cfdocumentitem  type="footer" evalAtPrint = "true" >
        This is Footer
    </cfdocumentitem>                        
    <cfinclude template="ReportData.cfm">
</cfdocument>
```

When I remove cfdocumentitem type="footer" code, it generates PDF right away.
What could be the reason? Anyone pls help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `This is Footer` this exact content of the footer or are there any images or links in there?

Comment: There is no image in the footer. Footer's real text is name of the report and datetime. However even sample 'This is footer' also takes 2+ hours of time to generate pdf.

Comment: It's likely the include not the footer. What happens when you remove the include or just run that on its own

Comment: Include works perfectly when I remove <cfpdf action="addHeader".

Comment: Have you inspected what the JVM is up to during those two hours (like with FusionReactor or similar)? That might help work out what's going on? Is this only occurring on one specific server / environment, or all? Can you update the sample code to be the minimum amount of code (including attributes on tags) to replicate? Don't have includes or anything that aren't portable, and are not relevant to replicating (reading: http://sscce.org/)